# Visual_basic : How to get single letters and letterstrings of 2 and 3 consecutive letters in the same label after clicking button?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Trying to make a Windows app with Visual basic (2015) for my kids to help them in their reading process.
Made 3 labels (`Box1`, `Box2`, `Box3`) that can contain 1 letter each, but also 2 or 3 letterstrings (like "ea" "ou", "tr", "str"...).
And a label with clickfunction, so the predefined letters change randomly, with each click, in each box.

I managed to get individual predefined single letters in the boxes, but can't find a way to get 2 consecutive letters in those boxes.
Anyone can help me.

Examples of outcome:

```
consonants  vowels      consonants
m           a           p           => map
m           a           rs          => mars
m           ea          n           => mean
m           ee          t           => meet
spr         i           ng          => spring
```

My VB-code uptill now is:

```vb
Public Class VLLK1_2

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim rand As New Random
        Dim letter As String = "gkmnprstv "
        Dim consonant As String = "gkmnprts "
        Dim vowel As String = "aei"
        letter = letter.Substring(rand.Next(letter.Length), 1)
        Box1.Text = letter
        vowel = vowel.Substring(rand.Next(vowel.Length), 1)
        Box2.Text = vowel
        consonant = consonant.Substring(rand.Next(consonant.Length), 1)
        Box3.Text = consonant
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: How do you imagine making sure that several randomly selected letters always make up a word?

Comment: Instead of pulling from a single string ("letter", "consonant", "vowel"), pull from a `List(Of String)` so that you can add any length string as a candidate to select from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im no word expert but wouldnt it be easier like the coment just mentioned to create List(of String) containing words that you want to learn. Then select randomly each word and divide it into 3 parts and add those parts into your textboxes?

```
Private rand As New Random
Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        Dim ListW As New List(Of String)
        ListW.Add("apple")
        ListW.Add("pinaple")
        ListW.Add("pen")
        ListW.Add("orange")
        ListW.Add("water")

        'select random word from list

        Dim randW As String = ListW(rand.Next(0, ListW.Count - 1))
        'Dim randW = "pinaple"

        'find the integer divider value
        Dim div As Integer = randW.Length / 3


        'divide the word into 3 parts
        Dim leftP As String = Strings.Left(randW, div)
        Dim midP As String = Strings.Left(Strings.Mid(randW, div + 1), div)

        Dim reminderLenght = randW.Length - (leftP.Length + midP.Length)

        Dim rightP As String = Strings.Right(randW, reminderLenght)

        'now add the parts to text boxes

        tb1.Text = leftP
        tb2.Text = midP
        tb3.Text = rightP
    End Sub
End Class
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use the list(of strings), without the words repeating themselves until all words in the list are used? So they only show again, after every word of the list has been generated.  If Yes, what would you propose ??

Comment: Of course it is possible. One way would be to SHUFFLE the list and then pull the items out in order.